# Word replacement of word "Check" with "Cheque" does not work everywhere

Tags: translation

CIVICRM 5.67 Wordpress 6.4.2
Example: In membership renewal, payment section most occurences are replaced but "Check Number" is not.
My question is: do I need to add replacements for the complete string such as "Check Number" with "Cheque Number" or is current situation a bug.
This is not in anyway high priority

Comment: So... you're replacing strings like "System Status Check" with "System Status Cheque"?

Comment: No that is the issue I can see. So question is what is best approach to get the result I want. "Check number" is incorrect but your example doesn't fall into that camp. What are the rules around context that I can follow

Comment: Have you considered changing the site language to en_GB? See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/#install-localization-files-optional

Comment: I am pretty certain that Wordpress and CIVICRM are set to be English (UK). That's what the settings panels in each tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see in the en_GB translations it hasn't been translated yet: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/blob/b5f52d09f30de9ce51e90400fa4b524f1fc4a879/po/en_GB/common-base.po#L12313. (Well, technically it has been translated, but it was probably auto-filled from the en_US. If it hadn't been translated yet you'd see a blank for the msgstr.) The right way to do this is to update it in transifex: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/wikis/home#translate-civicrm, and then eventually it will get included in the civi translation files.

In the meantime you could try using en_AU which appears to have it translated: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/-/blob/b5f52d09f30de9ce51e90400fa4b524f1fc4a879/po/en_AU/common-base.po#L12304

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. If the process is straightforward I will put down my compiler writing project and fix up some stuff. It isn't crucial that this is fixed now, I would prefer to invest in CIVICRM's future.